# How can I assign event handler to page objects using ajax and UJS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events, ujs

Can someone please advise a good approach to this problem:

On page load, an event handler is added to a page element. For example:

```
// Javascript
// when page is loaded...
jQuery(document).ready(function) {
  // assign this handler to the buttonDiv element...
  jQuery("#buttonDiv").click(function() {
    // to alert "hello"
    alert("hello");
  });
}


// HTML 5
<div id="buttonDiv">Click me </div>
```

This works as expected - GREAT!

But suppose the `div#buttonDiv` wasn't present when the document is loaded and is added to the DOM later using Ajax. In this case, the `click()` event handler is not added and no alert will be called.

How would one add an event handler to this element without using in-line javascript?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is for :) Like this:

```
jQuery(function) {
  jQuery("#buttonDiv").live("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) doesn't add an event handler when an element is added really, but it adds an event handler to `document` when you run it, and listens for `click` events that bubble up.  Since old and new elements bubble the same way...it doesn't matter when they were added, the `click` handler still works, as long as the selector matches.

There's also a similar [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (which even uses [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) internally) that you can use if you know the button will be inside a certain container, say you're re-loading the `#content` container via AJAX, it'd look like this:

```
jQuery(function) {
  jQuery("#content").delegate("#buttonDiv", "click", function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

This adds that listener for bubbling events at `#content` which just saves a few bubbles before catching it, as opposed to having it go all the way to `document`...in practice either are fine and you can't tell the performance difference, unless you're doing a *ton* of `.live()` event handlers.

Comment: Thanks Nick... That was a big help!